# How to achieve Left Excluding JOIN using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How to achieve Left Excluding JOIN using LINQ?

In [SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx):

```
SELECT <select_list> 
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.Key IS NULL
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need `DefaultIfEmpty()` for the `LEFT JOIN`, then you can check if the joined value is `null`:

```
var result = from a in Table_A
             join b in Table_B on a.Key equals b.Key into j
             from b in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where b == null
             select new { ... };
```

Answer (score 16):

Easier would be to write like this:

```
var result = from a in Table_A
             where !Table_B.Any(b => b.Key == a.key)
             select new { ... };
```

Comment: Is its SQL statement as optimized as dahlbyk's answer?

Comment: It will have even better performance. It will generate `NOT EXISTS` in SQL code.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the performance of `NOT EXISTS` vs `LEFT JOIN` depends on the structure of the database in question - check execution plans to be sure. In LINQ to Objects, the join would perform better because it builds a Lookup of `Table_B` once rather than scanning the table for every `Any()` - a SQL engine could reasonably use a similar implementation.

Comment: @dahlbyk I disagree, `NOT EXISTS` will outperform `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check every time. For more information on the subject read [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists). Since this question is marked with Linq2Sql, `ANY` will be the best solution. For Linq to objects on the other hand, you are correct, the `JOIN` would outperform `ANY`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little new to this, so what goes in the brackets of `select new{...}`? Would you do `select new{a}`? Would you mind providing a simple example with two simple tables?

Comment: @Lirik the columns you want to return: `select new { a.Column1, a.Column2 }`;

Comment: Are you positive it will *always* outperform? On an RDBMS, probably. But I'm less sure when working with IEnumerable in memory. In that case, I suspect the call to "Any" could result in O(N^2) or O(N*M) performance. Reading it literally, the "Where" method will run O(N) times. The "!Any" method will run O(M) times for each of the O(N) calls. Nested loops - your performance would completely die. The left outer join would tell LINQ to pull both lists in memory and perform a more efficient comparison.

Comment: @ShadowChaser As I wrote in my previous comment: "For Linq to objects on the other hand, you are correct, the JOIN would outperform ANY"

Answer (score 1):

An even faster way

```
var result = from a in Table_A
    where !Table_B.Select(b => b.Key).Contains(a.Key)
    select new { ... };
```