# How to join two tables using LINQ (using Query or method syntax) in Asp.Net Mvc project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, join, left-join

How is possible to show in my Select Option those products is not already in my Inventory table using LINQ (using Query or method syntax)..? 
In this image example I want to show only Server and Printer becouse they are not in my inventory table.
[image]

I'am trying to do like this but not working:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetInventory()
        {
            using (db)
            {

              var inventory = from p in db.Product
              join I in db.Inventory on I.ProductId equals p.ProductId
              where I.ProductId != p.ProductId
              select new { 
              ProductId = p.ProductId, ProductName = p.ProductName };
              return inventory;

         }
}
```

I can get only Products and Inventories  but not when I join them ...

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
        {

            return db.Products;
        }

public IQueryable<Inventory> GetInventory()
        {

            return db.Inventories;
        }

public class InventoryViewModel
    {
    public int Inventory { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    }
```

Then I have my Javascript function  to retrieve

```
function Products() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Api/GetInventory",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                $("#Products").append($("<option></option>").val(value.ProductId).html(value.ProductName));
            });
        }
    });
```

}

How can I modify my Action to get thos Product is not in my Inventory table? Thank you.

Comment: You are mixing to many things here, that's why you're not getting any response. Try to separate your problem. It doesn't look like it has anything to do with javascript etc. If something doesn't work, explain what exactly is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another LINQ only solution which I believe might be faster would be the following:

```
var result = db.Product
                .Where(p => !db.Inventory
                        .Any(i => i.ProductId == p.ProductId))
                .Select(p => new 
                {
                    ProductId = p.ProductId,
                    ProductName = p.ProductName
                });
```

Also as mentioned by @Shyju you should return the result as json using the following:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Which makes this the full snippet: (you might need to specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` if not using .net core)

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetInventory()
{
    var result = db.Product
                    .Where(p => !db.Inventory
                            .Any(i => i.ProductId == p.ProductId))
                    .Select(new 
                    {
                        ProductId = p.ProductId,
                        ProductName = p.ProductName
                    });
    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I don not get error, by Products didnt show in my option selectlist when I oppen it. It's empty list, Somewhere it is missing something...;) It's appear like a list it's long list but empty ...

Comment: That could be a ton of different things (db empty, select failing, you're not populating the dropdown correctly, etc.). In visual studio, can you set a breakpoint on the `return Json(result);` line and hover over the `result` variable and see if it contains anything? Feel free to post back with a link to a screenshot of the debug window open

Comment: perfect.. I added Select(a => new ProductViewModel with productId and ProductName .. woking fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your description I can only guess, but it looks like you want to build an ["Excluding Join" in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6662924/265165). I think you will be able to adapt to your own Tables by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Contains` method.

```
  var products = db.Products
                  .Where(x => db.Inventories
                                .Select(f => f.Product).Contains(x.Id)==false)
                  .Select(a=>new { ProductId=a.ProductIId,
                                   ProductName = a.ProductName})
                  .ToList();
```

Basically it queries the items from Products table which does not exist in Inventory table and convert that to a list of anonymous objects with `ProductId` and `ProductName` properties.

If your code is inside an MVC controller, you can use the `Json` method to return a list of items. If that action method is GET type, you need to explicitly use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` enum when you call Json method.

```
 return Json(products,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If your code is inside a web api controller, you cannot project the results to anonymous objects. So you can either skip the entire `Select` portion and return the `Product` objects. Keep in mind that if the Product class has other properties (other than `ProductId` and `ProductName`), those will be included in the result here. If you want to send only those 2 properties, you need to create a simple view model with only those 2 properties and use that in your projection part.

```
public class ProductVm
{
    public int ProductId { set; get; }
    public string ProductName { set; get; }
}

[Route("api/GetInventory")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage  Get()
{    
     var products = db.Products
                      .Where(x => db.Inventories
                                    .Select(f => f.Product).Contains(x.Id)==false)
                      .Select(a=>new ProductVm { ProductId=a.ProductIId,
                                                 ProductName = a.ProductName})
                      .ToList();     
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, products);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, in my Api action I get error like following .... Error CS1929 'IQueryable<Product>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains<int>(ParallelQuery<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<int>'

Comment: I tried with "IndexOf" Instead of Contains but allmost the same error message

Comment: [Contains method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641(v=vs.110).aspx) is an extension method defined in `System.Linq`. As long as you have a using statement to import it, it should work fine.

Comment: I have actually using System.Linq in my Project. But I tried @Nbokmans with litle modification it's working fine. I would thank you for your wonderfull help.